# How can I better optimise these DB queries/function flow?

Tags: javascript, node.js, optimization, mongoose, lodash

I've turned my hand from game dev to writing a supporting back-end. Thus far everything seems to work out but when i got to writing a friend system i ran into this function flow which seemed very dirty to me. And i'm certain i'm just hacking it together at this point. Any node.js wizards about to tell me how I can improve this?

Fairly certain i should be caching player lookups in Redis as well.

```
acceptfriend: function(req, res){
    //Find our user
    User.findById( req.decoded._id, function(err, user){
        //error occured
        if(err){
            return res.status(401).send(err);
        }
        //no user found
        if(!user){
            return res.status(401).json({
                succes: false,
                message: 'no user found with that id'
            } );
        }
        //Does the request exist?
        if( !_.any( user.social.friendRequests, {id: req.params.id} ) ){
            return res.status(401).json( {
                succes: false,
                message: 'friend request not found'
            } );
        }
        //find the user that belongs to the request
        User.findById( req.params.id, function(err, friend){
            //error occured
            if(err){
                return res.send(err);
            }
            //user doesnt exist
            if(!friend){
                return res.status(401).json({
                    succes: false,
                    message: 'no user found with that id'
                } );
            }
            //Pull the request from the friendRequests array
            user.social.friendRequests.pull( req.params.id );
            //Add the friend
            user.social.friends.addToSet( {
                user_id: friend._id,
                name: friend.username,
                corp: 'n/a'
            } );
            //Add the user to the friends list as well
            friend.social.friends.addToSet({
                user_id: user._id,
                name: user.username,
                corp: 'n/a'
            });
            //save the docs
            user.save();
            friend.save();
        } );
        //return success
        return res.status(200).json({
            success: true,
            message: 'friend succesfully added'
        });
    } );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1- First of all, you have a big function. You have to split it into some functions. Doing this you gain the possibility to test them with any testing framework.

2- Delegate the handle of error responses to the controller.

```
from -> return res.status(401).send(err);
to (with Promises)-> deferred.reject(err); 
to (normal way)   -> throw new Error(err);
```

3- You can use Promises to manage the asynchronous behaviour of node to clear the code.
I created an example, maybe is not working at first time, feel free to fix the incorrent references. The User ref, the 'acceptfriend' method...

Gist: https://gist.github.com/aitoraznar/b7099ad88ead0cdab256

```js
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var _ = require('lodash');
//var User = app.models.User;

var ERRORS = {
    userNotFoundError: {
        code: 401,
        success: false,
        message: 'no user found with that id'
    },
    friendRequestNotFoundError: {
        code: 401,
        success: false,
        message: 'friend request not found'
    },
    friendNotFoundError: {
        code: 401,
        success: false,
        message: 'no friend found with that id'
    }

}

var SUCCESS_MESSAGES= {
    friendAddedSuccessfully: {
        success: true,
        message: 'friend succesfully added'
    }
};

var userDAO = {
    /*
     *
     */
    getUserById: function(id) {
        var deferred = Promise.pending();

        User.findById(id, function(err, user) {
            //error occured
            if (err) {
                err.code = 401;
                return deferred.reject(err);
            }

            //no user found
            if (!user) {
                return deferred.reject(ERRORS.userNotFoundError);
            }

            deferred.resolve(user);
        });

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    /*
     * Does the request exist?
     */
    checkFriendRequest: function(user, friendId) {
        var deferred = Promise.pending();

        if (userDAO.haveFriendRequestFrom(user, friendId)) {
            deferred.resolve(user, friendId);
        } else {
            return deferred.reject(ERRORS.friendRequestNotFoundError);
        }

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    /*
     * 
     */
    haveFriendRequestFrom: function(user, friendId) {
        return _.any(user.social.friendRequests, {id: friendId });
    },

    /*
     * 
     */
    getFriend: function(user, friendId) {
        var deferred = Promise.pending();

        userDAO.getUserById(friendId)
            .then(function(friend) {
                deferred.resolve(user, friend);
            }, 
            function(error) {
                if (error === ERRORS.userNotFoundError) {
                    // Then the error is friend not found
                    // Override the error
                    error = ERRORS.friendNotFoundError;
                }

                return deferred.reject(error);
            });

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    /*
     * 
     */
    makeFriendship: function(user, friend) {
        var deferred = Promise.pending();

        //Pull the request from the friendRequests array
        user.social.friendRequests.pull(friend._id);

        //Add the friend
        user.social.friends.addToSet( {
            user_id: friend._id,
            name: friend.username,
            corp: 'n/a'
        } );
        //Add the user to the friends list as well
        friend.social.friends.addToSet({
            user_id: user._id,
            name: user.username,
            corp: 'n/a'
        });
        //save the docs
        user.save();
        friend.save();

        // Return the new friendship
        var friendship = {
            user: user,
            friend:friend
        };
        
        deferred.resolve(friendship);

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    /*
     *
     */
    friendRequestError: function(err) {
        var deferred = Promise.pending();

        // Propagate de error
        deferred.reject(err);

        return deferred.promise;
    },

    /*
     *
     */
    friendRequest: function(userId, friendId) {
        var deferred = Promise.pending();

        // Get user by ID
        userDAO.getUserById(userId)
            
            // Check if the user is able to add the friend
            .then(userDAO.checkFriendRequest, userDAO.friendRequestError)

            // Get the friend to add
            .then(userDAO.getFriend, userDAO.friendRequestError)

            // Make the friendship
            .then(userDAO.makeFriendship, userDAO.friendRequestError)

            // Response to the controller
            .then(
                function(friendship) {
                    // Resolve with new friendship
                    // This goes to 'success' function in controller
                    deferred.resolve(friendship);
                }, function(error) {
                    // This goes to 'error' function in controller
                    deferred.reject(error);
                })

        return deferred.promise;
    }
};


// Controller
var acceptfriend = function(req, res, next) {
    var userId = req.decoded._id;
    var friendId = req.params.id;

    userDAO.friendRequest(userId, friendId)
        .then(function(friendRequest) {
            console.log('---> SUCCESS');
            
            //return success
            return res.status(200)
                .json(SUCCESS_MESSAGES.friendAddedSuccessfully);
        }, function(error) {
            console.error('---> ERROR', error);

            return res.status(error.code).json(error);
        });
}
```

4- Create database indexes in the collection/table

Regards,
Aitor

Comment: wow, so thorough. Thank you very much for your time and telling me about Promises. Will read up on those. Though at point 2 your use throw new error but then use deferred.reject() any reason other then that promises do it already?

Comment: Sorry, I mixed two different solutions... If you use Promises, these must be used for all.
Anyway, the idea is to delegate the handle of the error in the cotnroller or other place that is not the DAO/service layer

Comment: So i've tried implementing this but running into a TypeError that Promise.promise is not a function. Couldn't find .pending() in the docs either. Any idea's? Code is wholly unchanged.

Comment: Seems those methods are actually deprecated. Wrapping it all in New Promise(resolve, reject) now. You might want to edit the answer.